# React native push notifcation to run a function on notification received

Tags: javascript, ios, push-notification, react-native, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to a run a function in javascript ( react native ) when a remote notification is received? Would a remote notification awake react native in background?

Or it should be done with Swift / Objective-C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Absolutely possible!** Check out the [documentation for `PushNotificationIOS`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html)

```
componentWillMount() {
  PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', this._onRemoteNotification);
}

_onRemoteNotification(notification) {
  // handle the notification
}
```

You'll need to [manually link the Library](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#manual-linking) and add listeners in your `AppDelegate.m` file.

This is also assuming you've already [configured your APNs with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW6).

Comment: what about with Android ? I am using react-native-firebase 's features for push notification and there is no such function that get triggered when push notification is received specially when app is killed/closed.

Comment: @Brad: Hi Brad, `PushNotificationIOS` will works even user have killed the app? Or it will only support background/foreground?